# A generalization of SLLN: Convergence of combination of iid variables

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

**Problem:** Let $(\varepsilon_i)_{i\geq 1}$ be a sequence of [iid random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables). Let $(x_i)_{i\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers.
Assume that:

1. $\mathbb E[|\varepsilon_1|]<\infty$ and $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_1]=0$.
2. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)^2$ is bouned for all $n$.

Prove that: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \varepsilon_i=0$ with probability $1$.

**Consequence:** If we choose $x_i=1$ for all $i$. Then (loosely speaking) above problem recovers the [strong law of large number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law).

**My question:** My teacher suggests that I can prove the problem using [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma). But, I have no idea how to apply it. Could anyone give me a hint. Thank you in advance!

---

**Edit:** Based on the useful comments below, the first condition is redundant. I mean: If the expectation is defined as Lebesgue Integral, then we have: $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_1]=0$ implies $\mathbb E[|\varepsilon|]<\infty$.

Therefore, the first condition should be rewritten: **"$\mathbb E[\varepsilon_1]=0$ in the sense of Lebesgue Integral"**.

It is important to note that, the problem does not hold for Cauchy distribution. Indeed, if $\varepsilon_1$ has Cauchy distribution, then $\mathbb E[\varepsilon]$ is undefined in the sense of Lebesgue Integral (see [mean of Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Mean)).

Comment: Is your first condition correct? It seems redundant in that $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ implies that $\mathbb{E}(|X|)\lt \infty$.

Comment: @fblundun Thank you very much for your comment. You may think about $X$ with density $f(x)=\frac{1}{2x^2}1_{|x|\geq 1}$. Then you will have $\mathbb E[X]=0$ and $\mathbb E[|X|]=\infty$.

Comment: In that example $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(|X|)$, since $f$ is zero for $x < 0$.

Comment: @fblundun no, the support is $\{x: |x|\geq 1\}$.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the modulus sign. But still $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{1}\frac{1}{2x}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2x}dx$ is the sum of two divergent integrals so is undefined rather than $0$. Just as $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xdx$ isn't zero despite $f(x) = x$ being an odd function.

Comment: Edit: upper limit on that 1st integral should be $-1$ rather than $1$ but the point still stands.

Comment: Indeed, $E[X] = 0$ implies $E[|X|] < \infty$, since $X = X^+ - X^-$, and for the expectation of $X$ to be defined and finite itself, we must have $E[X^+],E[X^-] < \infty$. Now $|X| = X^+ + X^-$ so the rest follows.

Comment: @fblundun and TersaLisbon Thank you so much for your explainations. I am still wondering about that. For example, if $X$ has Cauchy distribution (e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232967/what-makes-the-mean-of-some-distributions-undefined), then $E[X]$ is undefined using $X=X^+-X^-$. However, it is well known that the expectation of $X$ exists.

Comment: @Leon That last part is a problem. See, recall how we constructed the Lebesgue integral, going from step functions, to non-negative functions, to breaking a function into its non-negative and negative part and defining the integral as the sum of these parts , *provided they are finite*. So, while another logical way of thinking (to be precise, another theory of the integral, and these exist, e.g. the Henstock-Kurzweil integral) may give $E[X] = 0$, the Lebesgue expectation of the Cauchy random variable is not defined.

Comment: Ah ok, now, it is clearer to me! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Leon You are welcome. Just to inform you, I am working on an answer, that is attempting to modify the usual SLLN proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption involves the sum of squares of $x_i$, which would naturally appear if we look at the variance of partials sums of $x_i\varepsilon_i$; however, this is not allowed because $\varepsilon_i$ do not necessarily have a finite moment of order two. This issue will be overcame in the following way.

**Step 1:** it suffices to prove that
$$
2^{-N}\max_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 2^N}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\varepsilon_i\right\rvert\to 0 \mbox{ a.s.}.
$$
**Step 2:** in order to do that, we use truncation: for a fixed $N$, let
$$
\varepsilon_{i,\leqslant}^N:=\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert\leqslant 2^N \}}-\mathbb E\left[\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert\leqslant 2^N \}}\right],
$$
$$
\varepsilon_{i,\gt}^N:=\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert> 2^N \}}-\mathbb E\left[\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert>2^N \}}\right].
$$
Then $\varepsilon_i=\varepsilon_{i,\leqslant}^N+\varepsilon_{i,\gt}^N$ and it thus suffices to prove that
$$\tag{1}
Y_{N}:=2^{-N}\max_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 2^N}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\varepsilon_{i,\leqslant}^{N}\right\rvert\to 0 \mbox{ a.s. and }
$$
$$\tag{2}
Z_N:=2^{-N}\max_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 2^N}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\varepsilon_{i,\gt}^{N}\right\rvert\to 0 \mbox{ a.s.}.
$$
**Step 3:** For (1): we show that $\sum_{N\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[Y_N^2\right]$ is finite. This follows from Kolomorov's maximal inequality, inequality
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\varepsilon_{i,\leqslant}^N\right)^2\right]\leqslant 2
\mathbb E\left[\left(\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert\leqslant 2^N \}}\right)^2\right],
$$
the fact that $\varepsilon_i$  have the same distribution, the assumption on $x_i$ and that $\sum_{N\geqslant 1}2^{-N}\mathbf{1}_{\{1\leqslant \lvert \varepsilon_1\rvert\leqslant 2^N\}}\leqslant \frac 1X\mathbf{1}_{1\leqslant \lvert \varepsilon_1\rvert}$.

**Step 4:** in order to prove (2), we first notice that $2^{-N}\sum_{i=1}^{2^N}\lvert x_i\rvert \mathbb E\left[\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert>2^N \}}\right]\to 0$. By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we are reduced to prove that for each $\delta$, $$\sum_N\mathbb P\left(2^{-N}\max_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 2^N}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert> 2^N \}}\right\rvert>\delta\right)<\infty.$$
To this aim, we use the inclusion
$$
\left\{2^{-N}\max_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 2^N}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\varepsilon_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert> 2^N \}}\right\rvert>\delta
\right\}\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{2^N}\{\lvert\varepsilon_i\rvert> 2^N \}.$$ Consequently, the previously mentioned probabilities can be controlled by a union bound and convergence of the aforementioned series follows from integrability of $\varepsilon_1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer!